# clean url or team page

Tags: .htaccess, url

I am trying to make clean url of this page

localhost/sports/ftp_team.php?team_id=8&team_name=England

result I want

localhost/sports/ftp/team/England

I tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ftp/team/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ ftp_team.php?team_name=$1
RewriteRule ^/ftp/team/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ ftp_team.php?team_name=$1
```

I have another page with name ftp.php which is running fine like this

localhost/sports/ftp

localhost/sports/ftp.php

but above htaccess code redirect me to ftp page not sure why.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ftp/team/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ ftp_team.php?team_name=$1
RewriteRule ^/ftp/team/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ ftp_team.php?team_name=$1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code. Do you have 2 .htaccess files in your system? OR a single one?

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a leading slash.

Comment: And where is your .htaccess file located, is it inside the `sports` folder? If not, and it was on the level above, that folder would be missing in what you are trying to match.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i am using only one .htaccess file but not sure how pages are running without .php also.

Comment: @CBroe .htaccess present in main folder
localhost/sportsupcoming/here

Comment: How is that supposed to match up with `localhost/sports/` then?